# Снять редирект c www на основной сайт

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

Есть основной сайт http://site.ru. На него стоял редирект с https://www.site.ru на https://site.ru
Во фронтенде стоит apache, в бекэнде nginx
Убрал редитекр с www

1. В DNS перевел сайта [www.site.conf](http://www.site.conf) на чыждой не действующий ip (пинги идут на него)
2. В виртуальном домене nginx по адресу /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.ru.conf
3. В виртуальном домене apache  по адресу /etc/httpd/conf.d/site.conf
   Но в результате все равно редирект работает без изменений.
   Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я пропустил

Comment: перезагрузка сервера DNS?

Comment: Кэш браузера вы не берете в расчет!

Comment: Да, вся проблема в браузере была, вопрос решен, спасибо